# Clementine / Show Tray Icon

Tags: icons, system-tray, 17.10, gnome-shell

Just moved from Unity to Gnome with the update to 17.10.
How does one make the Clementine Tray Icon reappear ? I've been through Clem' and the correct tick box is ticked. 17.10 seems not to want to show it. There are one or two other tray icons missing as well.
Is this Gnome standard or a "learning curve" for me.
Can anyone help with the icons ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Indicator icons does not appear after upgrade to ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966987/indicator-icons-does-not-appear-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-17-10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Ubuntu appindicators* extension which shows the system tray app icons in the top bar, fails to (properly) show some app icons (for example electron based app like Skype, Thunderbird with Firetray etc.).

As a workaround you may try any of the following extensions:

- [TopIcon](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/495/topicons/): Shows legacy tray icons on top
- [TopIcons Plus](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1031/topicons/): Same as above with more customisations like icon size, spacing etc.

Logout and login after activting the extension(s).