# Indicator icons do not appear after upgrade to Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: gnome, 17.10, icons, indicator, gnome-shell

Only GNOME extension and native icons are displayed. Other icons like Dropbox, shutter, enpass etc. do not appear in the top bar.

Am I missing something? I already tried using extensions that I used with GNOME before but nothing (Topicons Plus, Ubuntu appindicators etc.) seems to help.

Currently I'm using Ubuntu Xorg, but in Wayland I have the same issue.

Comment: Indicator implementation seems like a royal mess now especially when upgrading from an older release. Try this too: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/615/appindicator-support/

Comment: I juste migrated to Ubuntu 17.10. This extension doesn't work for me. Nothing's displayed :'(

Comment: \o/ It was intended! System tray has been removed in Gnome 3.26 http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/09/will-you-miss-gnome-legacy-tray

Comment: The same with 18.04

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I've encountered the same problem. I tried to remove the indicator-application-service completely, and see, the problem went away!
I guess coming from 16.04 leaves some Unity-related stuff on my machine that is not only obsolete but prevents the AppIndicator extension from properly working.

What to do:

```
sudo apt remove indicator-application
```

Comment: Did not work in my case....

Comment: @TylerDurden have you enabled the AppIndicator Gnome Shell Extension? My way of doing it is similar to the solution described at https://askubuntu.com/a/967226/751074, but permanent

Comment: Yes that extension seems to have fixed it, but the icons aren't in the bottom left anymore. Any idea why they changed that?

Comment: Because Ubuntu Appindicator moves these icons from bottom left to tray panel.

Comment: Worked for me, after restarting Gnome Shell --- press `Alt + f2` and execute the command `r`.

Comment: Great works really nice with: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/615/appindicator-support/ to have the indicators on te top bar. I would suggest adding `kilall indicator-application-service` like @amDude1848 suggested after the uninstall to get immediate effect.

Answer (score 30):

I have the same problem with 17.10. At least the following command helps here to bring the icons back until the next reboot:

```
killall indicator-application-service
```

Edit: This workaround is running fine here without using any gnome-extension like "Topicon-plus" or "Kstatusnotifieritem/appindicator support".

Comment: Yes, in Ubuntu 17.10. Directly after upgrading from 17.04 to 17.10 the indicators were shown, but after rebooting Ubuntu not anymore. With this upper workarround i can bring them back until next reboot.

Comment: Cool! Theoretically one can then auto-execute this command at startup and won't have to bother again.

Comment: Yeah thanks for the solution. I had the same idea and I am going to do this. :-)

Comment: Yes, i am use an extension called "Kstatusnotifieritem/appindicator support", but i am not sure if it works because of the extension. Got this tip from OMGUbuntu-Website.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67434/discussion-between-pomsky-and-amdude1848).

Comment: Skype-indicator is not working here too, but Coffein, Twitch-indicator or Clementine-indicator are working fine.

Comment: Thanks works perfect, at least is a temporal solution. In other place I can read a sugestion to execute ` sudo apt-get remove gnome-shell-extension-appindicator` but I'm not sure because a message indicate that other packages will be removed too " ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-gnome-desktop"

Comment: I reported the bug on launchpad, if you are affected please subscribe for visibility: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-application/+bug/1728449

Comment: Had problems with Dropbox on 18.04, showing a strange red "stop sign" instead of the icon, and the right-click menu only showed a few pixels high dropdown w/o content. This answer worked: Had to run "dropbox stop" on cmd-line, do the killall mentioned here, and then start dropbox again from App-launcher menu. Bam! Dropbox icon back and working!

Answer (score 5):

As suggested [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-application/+bug/1728449/comments/4), try removing all obsolete indicators if any still present

```
indicator-application
indicator-appmenu
indicator-bluetooth
indicator-common
indicator-datetime
indicator-keyboard
indicator-messages
indicator-network
indicator-power
indicator-printers
indicator-session
indicator-sound
indicator-transfer
indicator-transfer-download-manager
```

Just execute this command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt purge indicator-application indicator-appmenu indicator-bluetooth indicator-common indicator-datetime indicator-keyboard indicator-messages indicator-network indicator-power indicator-printers indicator-session indicator-sound indicator-transfer indicator-transfer-download-manager
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution is delete `Indicator-application` autostart .desktop file. It's installed in

`/etc/xdg/autostart/indicator-application.desktop`

If you dont want to remove it and sometimes is using Unity 7. This made `Indicator-application` not start at login.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I was trying so many things which didn't work.

Comment: Thanks ! My indicator would not close if I try to quit the app using Budgie desktop on Debian 10. Removing the ayatana-indicator-application.desktop solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing from suggested works for Shutter app in Ubuntu 18.04 as libgtk2-appindicator-perl package has been removed from main repo. To enable the Shutter indicator in Ubuntu 18.04 install libappindicator-dev:

```
libappindicator-dev
```

and Gtk2::AppIndicator perl extension:

```
sudo cpan -i Gtk2::AppIndicator
```

Restart Shutter, its indicator should appear now in system tray.

Comment: The only suggestion that actually displayed the Shutter icon.

Comment: There's a PPA that brings back the AppIndicator for Shutter, and every other feature missing due to removed dependencies (even those that are no longer available in Ubuntu for a long time, like the feature to take a screenshot of a website): https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/10/shutter-removed-from-ubuntu-1810-and.html

Answer (score 1):

In all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install indicator-applet-complete
```

Indicator-applet is an applet to display information from various applications consistently in the GNOME panel. This instance will load all indicators in a single panel applet.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on 18.04 (upgraded from version 16).

After following other suggestions such as wiping the old indicator-* programs, and installing the "Kstatusnotifieritem extension", my icons returned **-yay-**

..but they went away **every time** the laptop went to lock/or was closed for awhile. Which is often.

Everything comes back, but you have to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> every time, which is annoying and also rearranges my bottom bar dock thing, and since I have *many* terminals open and arranged, you can imagine :x.

Anyway, [this post seems to have fixed it](https://github.com/ubuntu/gnome-shell-extension-appindicator/issues/75#issuecomment-441011497).

> Removing default ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com from /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions

aka

```
sudo rm -r /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
```

I locked it with <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to test it - and my icons did not go away. :D

Answer (score 0):

Click the nine dots on your dock.

[image: applications icon]

At the search field write "tweak". You will see gnome tweak tools:

[image: searching gnome tweak tools]

If you don't have it installed you can click it and that will open software center. You can install it from there.

After, run tweaks and go to extensions.

[image: appindicator on tweak tools]

Just turn the appindicators on and you will have a working system tray where you can see the dropbox, telegram or other icons.

Comment: Added two screenshots and a better explanation. Didn't do it before because my system is in portuguese, but I think it's clear anyway.

Comment: This solution works and does not need to uninstall anything. Just uses the "Ubuntu Tweak" tool.

Comment: I meant "gnome-tweak-tool"; not "ubuntu-tweak", which I wrote in the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of [enolive's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/968305/18665) and [amDude1848's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/967226/18665) seems to be necessary.

This will fix the problem in the current session:

```
killall indicator-application-service
```

And this will prevent the problem from reoccurring:

```
sudo apt remove indicator-application
```