# Ubuntu 17.10 notification icons not working

Tags: gnome, notification, 17.10, gnome-shell-extension, notification-area

So I just installed Ubuntu 17.10 and everything seems to be working fine, but there is a little problem. When there is an app, that should have an app indicator, it is nowhere to be found. In previous versions, it was located in the top right, along with the power off menu. In Ubuntu GNOME, they were located in the bottom left.

I have tried installing two different extensions, but none of them seems to work. I tried these: 
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1031/topicons/
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/615/appindicator-support/

Comment: Can I do anything to get them back, or is it just a hard fact?

Comment: It seems like a huge mess now. There are already ~10 questions posted here since the release of Artful. See if this works for you: https://askubuntu.com/a/967226/

Comment: Thanks, will try that! I hope, that Canonical is going to iron out those little things like app indicators in the next release (or maybe even this one)...

Comment: Ok, so I had no luck with using the mentioned command. There is no such process.

Comment: The main issue is it's behaving differently for different people/session/mode-of-installation (fresh or upgrade), no uniform behaviour :(

Comment: Weird...I have a fresh install...Just found out, that in gnome-tweak-tool, extensions, there is a warning sign standing by Ubuntu appindicators (preinstalled extension). When I put my cursor on the warning sign, it says "Error loading extension". I am probably going to wait for the situation to calm down a little...

Comment: This is a design decision by the GNOME developers. File a bug report / feature request with them and/or the developers of the applications that keep using obsolete desktop notification API.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Indicator icons does not appear after upgrade to ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966987/indicator-icons-does-not-appear-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-17-10)