# Indicator icons not working/missing in Unity (18.04)

Tags: unity, icons, indicator, 18.04, dock

I remember this being an issue back in 17.10 but I can't seem to find the answer that worked that time.

Basically the indicator that showed the amount of messages on top of the dock icons in Unity is gone (hexchat, skype, etc), and while there's some solutions for Gnome like this [Indicator icons do not appear after upgrade to Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966987/indicator-icons-do-not-appear-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-17-10) or even this https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/9046 (using `export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity` in the respective .desktop files), those don't seem to work for Unity or aren't working for this latest version. So far it seems to be the only issue I've found during the transition from 17.10 to 18.04.

What should I try next?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the fix is same as before however the xdg variable has changed to ubuntu:GNOME

Comment: Just so we're clear on what you are saying, do you mean changing `export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity` to `export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu.Gnome` ? Please [edit] your post to include your recommendation. Thank you!

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. Specifically, what I did was modify, for example, hexchat.desktop in `~/.local/share/applications/`, and changed the previous Exec line from `Exec=env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity hexchat %U` to `Exec=env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu.Gnome hexchat %U`. It still failed to show the message count in the top right of the icon (not the top bar, mind you-- maybe some are misunderstanding this).