# Why top panel icons disapear on Gnome after installing Unity?

Tags: unity, 18.04, icons, gnome-shell

Why are some icons missing from the top panel on Gnome after installing Unity on Ubuntu 18.04?

I have the extension Topicons plus, but just the icons which do not depend on this extension have disappeared like Skype, Telegram, Thunderbird with Firetray.

When I type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, then `r`, the icons re-appear but I need to do this after every restart.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

It also seems to happen after Ubuntu upgrade. Gnome is conflicting with unity stuff in this case. See this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/968305/452552) and other below.

So, if you want gnome instead of unity as in my case, I've just removed the obsolete package:

```
sudo apt remove indicator-application
```

Then reboot the system or [do this for immediate effect](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966987/indicator-icons-do-not-appear-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-17-10/968305#comment1712358_968305)

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the value of "`Exec`" in `/etc/xdg/autostart/indicator-application.desktop` with

```
Exec=dbus-launch /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-application/indicator-application-service
```

to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remove compiz application. That application makes gnome topbar unable to work after every restart or after every unlock.

`sudo apt remove --purge compiz`

Since I can't comment I have written this answer. 
Accept if found useful.