# Icons show up in launcher but not in panel

Tags: icons, taskbar

I can't see any icons ( telegram/hangouts/viber and etc.) in the panel of Ubuntu 16.04. They do show up in the launcher though:

[image: Dezsktop screenshotre]

*How should I proceed?*

I don't have any of this installed:

indicator-application
indicator-appmenu
indicator-bluetooth
indicator-common
indicator-datetime
indicator-keyboard
indicator-messages
indicator-network
indicator-power
indicator-printers
indicator-session
indicator-sound
indicator-transfer
indicator-transfer-download-manager

So [Indicator icons do not appear after upgrade to Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966987/indicator-icons-do-not-appear-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-17-10) don't solve my problem. Any suggestions please?

I just change some files in .local/share/applications because the icon of hangouts don't show up in the panel. And after that all icons don't show in the panel. How can i reset to the defaults files in .local/share/applications ? Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Indicator icons do not appear after upgrade to Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966987/indicator-icons-do-not-appear-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-17-10)

Comment: @Fabby it is not duplicate, i tried all from this

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give a description of what went wrong with the existing answers.

Comment: @Fabby I just change some files in .local/share/applications because the icon of hangouts don't show up in the panel. And after that all icons don't show in the panel. How can i reset to the defaults files in .local/share/applications ?

Comment: By restoring your back-up or if you don't have one, create a new user and copy its files over to yours **and then start making backups.  :P**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution for me. It is works.

`sudo apt-get install indicator-applet-complete`